# How to rollback to specific point after commit?

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

I have a table A in which I am inserting some rows. After that, I am calling a function myFunction which selects those rows from table A, does some extra things and inserts into table B.

But if something goes wrong in the myFunction, I want to remove the rows created in table A as well. How can I do that?

Note: myFunction is inserting into table B using transaction, and I cannot update anything in myFunction.

I am using golang with MySQL.

Since I need the rows in table A to be committed before calling myFunction (there is `select from table A` statement in myFunction), I can't use a single transaction for both of the insertions and I guess I can't use savepoints as well.

So is there some way to achieve this without having to explicitly delete the rows from table A when something goes wrong in myFunction?

Comment: I agree with your assessment -- MySQL doesn't have nested transactions and you can't create a savepoint outside the transaction that myFunction starts. I don't see a way around having to delete the records. (Or at least marking them as invalid.)

Comment: "Since I need the rows in table A to be committed before calling myFunction". Why is that?

Comment: @slaakso maybe an issue with connection pools and not being able to guarantee the same connection is used in myFunction?

Comment: Also note that starting a second transaction (i.e., the one in myFunction) makes an implicit commit on any open transaction.

Comment: @ysth Could be, but there is nothing in the question about another connection.

Comment: @AlexHowansky. If the function (procedure?) does the it's inserts based on the first   inserted rows in A, it would be logical to have those committed as well. That was the reason for the question.

Comment: @slaakso the function called after the first insertion executes a select statement from various tables including table A, that's why I need those rows to be committed.

Comment: @Ankur Is the function called after the first insertion from the same session ? If so, why not putting them in the same transaction?  Uncommitted insertion can still be read.

Comment: @Ankur The rows inserted in the first statement are visible to the function without a commit, so the original question remains. Why do you need to commit the first inserts before the function execution?

Comment: @slaakso, maybe the function is executed from another session. In that case , unless that session has its system variable `transaction_isolation` level set to `read-uncommitted`, it cannot see the uncommitted contents from a different session. I have yet to get a reply from the OP.

Comment: @blabla_bingo See the discussion above. No mention about another session/connection.

Comment: I am new to go code, but looks like it is using same connection. Thanks for clarification that the uncommitted rows are visible. Although another question is that the function is starting its own transaction, so would that be a problem (since MySQL doesn't support nested tx)?

Comment: If that function starts its own transaction, there will be an implicit commit , so the uncommitted contents are committed right away.  But is that possible you make a new function which starts a transaction , then does the insertion and execute the contents of the original function without the original function's own transaction?  If everything is put in one transaction, we are free to use savepoints and so on.